# add & editting timestamp to JSON twitter jQuery

Tags: jquery, json, twitter

I was able to add a timestamp (the question/problem below)... but now I'm having issues formatting it.

I'd love for it to be "14 minutes ago" or even just the date with the time.
Can anyone help with this? (And if you give me the code, can you tell me where to put it too...)

Thanks!

*Here's what I changed in the code to add the timestamp:*

```
list.append(element.append(paragraph.html(linkify(value.text)).append("<br /><i>@myadorkablelife "+value.created_at+"</i>")));
```

I've been trying to add a timestamp to my twitter feed for a while, nothing seems to be working. (Ideally, it'd be nice to have any appropriate links function like links as well... so bonus points if you can help me with that!)

Here's what I've got on my site:

```
 this.createTwitter=function()
  {
    $.getJSON('http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name='+$this.twitterName+'&count='+$this.twitterEntryCount+'&callback=?',function(data) 
    {
      if(data.length)
      {
        var list=$(document.createElement('ul'));         

        $(data).each(function(index,value)
        {
          var element=$(document.createElement('li'));              
          var paragraph=$(document.createElement('p'));

          list.append(element.append(paragraph.html(linkify(value.text))));
        });

        $('#latest-tweets').append(list);

        list.bxSlider(
        {
          auto:true,
          pause:5000,
          nextText:null,
          prevText:null,              
          mode:'vertical',
          displaySlideQty:1
        });

        list.find('a').attr('target','_blank');
      }
    });      
  };
```

If you need to see the site to view the source better, let me know. jQuery is not my thing, but normally I can search and find what I need.

Comment: Do you need a human readable timestamp or like, the unix timestamp (since the epoch) ?

Comment: human readable. I just want it to go: "this is my latest tweet" 2 days ago. or even July 19 7:52am... just so people have some sort of reference of when said tweet happened.

Comment: I saw from other comments that the "timeago" plugin will work to change the format...but I can't seem to get that to work either. Help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each Tweet has a "created_at" attribute which is human readable:

```
"created_at":"Thu Jul 19 07:59:51 +0000 2012"
```

In your case, just call

```
value.created_at
```

To get the value of the timestamp.

If you want to get the time (for use in calculations) use

```
new Date(value.created_at)
```

[JavaScript should be able to recognise and parse that string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/).

Comment: I got that code to work. Thanks!
Any tips on how to change the format of the date?

Comment: tweetDate = new Date(value.created_at) - then you can get the month, for example, by using tweetDate.getMonth() - all the methods are listed at https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/

Comment: That worked, however, with the month set up, it says that it's June instead of July. I'll keep tinkering with it. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: In Javascript, months start at zero. January = 0, December = 11

Answer (score 2):

If you want timeago text (like "10 minutes ago"), you should try out [Livestamp.js](http://mattbradley.github.com/livestampjs). You can do something like this:

```
var livestamp = $('<span />').livestamp(new Date(created_at));
list.append(element.append(paragraph.html(linkify(value.text)).append(livestamp)));
```

It'll update automatically as time goes by.